# php httprequest class and session

Tags: php, session

I am using the httprequest class in one of my applications to request a cross domain page. Basically I needed to inlcude two pages based on thge logged in state of the user, via cross domain ajax request. Due to security issues this is not allowed.

So what I did was I created a proxy page which uses the httprequest class to request the remote file which inturn includes the two apges based on the logged in state of the user.

Now the issue is that each time the httprequest class is making a new request thus the session is getting destroyed, so once I am logged in and I refresh the page next time the class is sending a new request and thus creating a new session, so the logged in user is getting logged out.

What I need to do is maintain the same session over several http requests., untill the user opts to logout.

I have observed in firebug that the http request is sending the PHPSESSID cookie, but there is nothing being sent from the server in response. Does it make any sense?

How can I do this using php cookies? Kindly help.

Comment: This should be on http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: Which httprequest class are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass along the cookies between browser and that remote server. I'm working on [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573175/what-to-use-from-zend-framework-for-implementing-a-proxy) right now but I'll give you a simpler example:

**proxy.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION['remote_session_id'])) {

    $response = make_initial_request();

    /*
     * This means to read the Set-Cookie header and store it in your own session
     */
    $_SESSION['remote_session_id'] = $remote_session_id = get_remote_session_id($response);

} else {
    /*
     * Inside this function you must send a Cookie header populated with the value
     * of $remote_session_id. Its name is dependent on the remote server.
     */
    $response = make_remote_request($_SESSION['remote_session_id']);
}
```

Comment: @Stan Many thanks for your kind help. I have solved the isue using an iframe. Its working pretty kool though.